# Declare a Hilt module as object or class

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am watching this tutorial on youtube, called Hilt - Providing Retrofit Instance and Repository. Here is a piece of code:

```
    @Module
    @installin(SingletonComponent::class)
    object NetworkModule{
           @singleton
           @provides
           fun provideabc()...
     }
```

I know that `object` creates a singleton, i.e a single NetWork module for the whole application, but in some books I read, they use the keyword `class`. Is there any difference between `object NetworkModule` and `class NetworkModule`? I have tried swapping them and there was no error. The code worked fine.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: I suspect there is difference when you use `@Binds` or any other annotation that requires hilt to generate a subclass of your module, because named objects are not subclassable

Answer (score 1):

If you open this link https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#6
you will find the answer.

> In Kotlin, modules that only contain @Provides functions can be object classes. This way, providers get optimized and almost in-lined in generated code.

I realize when we use Kotlin Object which is a static class, can help dagger to generate efficient codes it is made once especially when you don't define singleton scope which means provide every time when using it like this code below.

```
@provides
fun provideabc()
```